# Creating .htaccess files (Ubuntu Server 12.04 w/ Apache2)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, vps, digital-ocean

Whenever I create an `.htaccess` file in a directory it disappears. I am running a VPS at Digital Ocean (I have full control over the server). So I can't see why my `.htaccess` files are automatically deleted upon creation. I even tried to make the file on my computer and just transfer it to the directory via FTP but as soon as it transfers, it disappears. I checked the log of the FTP transfer and the file transferred successfully. I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because system files are hidden on apache servers... Either select the option to see hidden files if you're using a GUI or type the command  "ls -a" if you're on terminal  and you should see the files. Any file that starts with a dot is going to be hidden by default. Your .htaccess files fall within the same category.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm "fairly" new to using Ubuntu Server. I know my way around and I can do what I need to, but little commands like that haven't made themselves known to me just yet. Now to get my ModRewrite to work. I also figured that I'd be able to see the .htaccess files from FileZilla.

Comment: Logging in for the first time since replying to your answer. I face-palmed when I read my question. I have, in fact, learned a great deal since posting that question.

Thank you for your courteous answer back then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to view the .htaccess file on the server, make sure you are logged in as the root user, or a user with root level permissions.

Then, navigate yourself to "/home/username/public_html(in my case)" And if you have a .htaccess file uploaded, it should be displayed there.